# get? have? take? Any difference in term of buying?

Tags: word-difference

> I'll **get** this shoe.
>   I'll **have** this shoe.
>   I'll **take** this shoe.

What's the difference in my examples when using these three verbs?

EDIT:

More context about **to have**,below is a passage from my English textbook, how do you explain **to have** within this passage? Especially the one in the last wentence.

> Just then, a man hurried to the ticket office.
>
> 'Can I return these two tickets?' he asked.
>
> 'Certainly,' the girl said.
>
> I went back to the ticket office at once.
>
> 'Could I **have** those two tickets please?' I asked.
>
> 'Certainly,' the girl said, 'but they're for next Wednesday's performance. Do you still want them?'
>
> 'I might as well **have** them,' I said sadly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're asking here? The dictionary will give some general differences between these.

Comment: @Paul Dexter Assuming that I'm in a shop and going to buy a pair of shoes, should I say I'll get/have/take this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the scenario of buying shoes in a shop**
Note: These differences may vary regionally or even between individuals.  In the US, we'll most often use 'get' to refer to the situation of getting shoes:

> I'll *get* new shoes only when I really need them.
>   Do you sell shoes here? I want to *get* sturdy ones for hiking.
>   Did you decide which shoes you want to *get*?
>   Want to see the shoes I *got*?

Whereas we'll probably use 'take' at the moment of agreeing to buy a particular pair of shoes from the salesperson:

> I didn't plan to *get* running shoes, but you've convinced me.  I'll *take* these light ones. (gets out money to pay)

'Have' can be used for agreeing to buy food, but not other things like shoes.  With shoes, 'have' would only refer to ongoing ownership:

> I *have* five pairs of shoes.  After tomorrow, I'll *have* six.

Comment: +1 for have & food.  "I'll have the cheeseburger".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question to add some more context about _to have_.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there is no difference between buy and get, 
Let me give you an example.

> "Nick’s going to get tickets for all of us."

"get" here simply means the same as bought in this example :

> "He’s just bought himself a new van."
>   And about take, " I'll take this shoe" does NOT seem to be quite common in compare to the two previous expressions ( get / buy )

You know, if something takes a particular amount of money, that amount of money is needed for it to happen or succeed,  if a business takes a particular amount of money, it receives that amount of money from its customers and it's commom in BrE and in AmE people often use "take in" with this meaning :

> e.g. The stall took $2000 on Saturday!